# Which connective to use when translating the statement $∀x(−2 < x < 3)$ to words?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

$$ ∀x(−2 < x < 3)$$

Does the above read as “for all x, $x > -2$ **and** $< 3$”
or as “$ x > -2$ **or** $< 3$” ?

I want  to know which one to use, in order to be able to determine how to correctly negate the statement.

Comment: AND , because OR means $x$ can be $< -2$ or $x  >3$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: All reals are $>-2$ or $<3$ !

Comment: My understanding is it should be AND b/c the restrictions make it have to be between -2 and 3. if it were OR, that would essentially mean x could be any number. x being any number breaks the restrictions of the initial statement, and also changes the meaning of the initial statement @islamm

Comment: @iSuckatMath yes the answer is AND

Comment: Wrong, @Yves.  $x \in (-2, 3)$.

Comment: @amWhy: what is wrong in what I wrote ? What is this $x$ ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In an inequality like $$7<2x+1<15,$$ $x$ simultaneously satisfies *both*
   $$7<2x+1\tag2$$ **and** $$2x+1<15\tag3,$$ so the solution set is the
   **intersection** of $(2)$ and $(3).$
2. On the other hand, in an inequality like $$|x|>3,$$ $x$ satisfies *either*
   $$x<-3\tag5$$ **or** $$x>3\tag6$$  (*or* sometimes even *both* inequalities), so the solution
   set is the **union** of $(5)$ and $(6).$

P.S. Either a number line or Venn diagram helps to visualise taking the aforementioned intersection or union of sets of numbers.